# Create JavaScript function which cannot be called as constructor?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to prevent a new defined function to be called as constructor in JavaScript? Like throw out error when placing `new` before calling it.

Comment: Just so you know, the solutions given below (except for the arrow function) are  fragile in that they rely on the variable scope or prototype chains being unaltered.

Comment: ECMAScript 6 has a specific tool for this. You can use [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) in a function to determine if `new` was used to invoke it. `console.log(new.target)` will show `undefined` if `new` was not used, otherwise you get a reference to the function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a function was called with `new` by seeing if it is an instance of itself

```
function test() {
    if ( this instanceof test ) {
        throw "Oh God no, not a new one !"
    }
}

var a = test(); // success
var b = new test(); // fail
```

In ES2015 the [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) meta property lets you check directly if `new` was used to call the method

```
function test() {
    if (new.target) {
        throw "Oh God no, not a new one !"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check `this.constructor` inside the function:

```
function f() {
  if (this && this.constructor === f) {
    throw new Error("Don't call f as a constructor")
  }
}

f();     // ok
new f(); // throws
```

As @squint points out, it is possible to break this check if `f.prototype.constructor` is set explicitly:

```
f.prototype = {
  constructor: "not f!"
}

new f(); // doesn't throw
```

Comment: `f === g` in the second example, so why not use `f`? That also protects it from outside mutation when `var` or `let` are used.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that named function expressions bind the function to its name inside the function body.

Answer (score 1):

If your environment supports them, you could use an arrow function:

```
const f = () => "test"
f()       // returns "test"
new f()   // throws TypeError: f is not a constructor(…)
```

Note that arrow functions inherit `this` from the scope that they are defined in. That's different from `function` (where `this` usually depends on how the function is called), so you can't always use them as a drop-in replacement.

Babel currently does not throw an Exception if an arrow function is called as a constructor: [Babel REPL example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=const%20f%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%22test%22)%20%7D%3B%0A%0Af()%3B%0A%0Anew%20f()%3B).

[Arrow function compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-arrow_functions)